# Go install fails with error: no install location for directory xxx outside GOPATH

Tags: macos, go

```
~/src/go-statsd-client> echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/gopath
~/src/go-statsd-client> echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1.1\
~/src/go-statsd-client> go install
go install: no install location for directory /Users/me/src/go-statsd-client outside GOPATH
```

No matter what structure the project is in this always fails with the same message. Go build works perfectly.

Here is my `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/me/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1.1"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1.1/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

This is on Mac OSX Mountain Lion and go was installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

When you provide no arguments to `go install`, it defaults to attempting to install the package in the current directory. The error message is telling you that it cannot do that, because the current directory isn't part of your `$GOPATH`.

You can either:

- Define `$GOPATH` to your $HOME (`export GOPATH=$HOME`).
- Move your source to within the current `$GOPATH` (`mv ~/src/go-statsd-client /User/me/gopath`).

After either, going into the `go-statsd-client` directory and typing `go install` will work, and so will typing `go install go-statsd-client` from anywhere in the filesystem. The built binaries will go into `$GOPATH/bin`.

As an unrelated suggestion, you probably want to namespace your package with a domain name, to avoid name clashing (e.g. `github.com/you/go-statsd-client`, if that's where you hold your source code).

Comment: In my case this error was caused by there not being a `$GOPATH/bin` directory. Creating this folder was that was needed -- I didn't need to set `GOBIN` env var.

Comment: @RobertReiz while I share your frustration, I should point out that most other languages do in fact use these, but maybe they're not as visible. For example, Python (a language famous for its simplicity) has `PYTHONHOME` instead of `GOROOT` and `PYTHONPATH` instead of `GOPATH`. Even (GC)C has `LIBRARY_PATH`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, etc.

Comment: What argumen can I give to go install to install it where GOPATH point and not in the current directory ? I have 6 project using the same dependency and I don't want to install it 6 times, specially because I need to keep them in sync.

Comment: I get this error after `export GOPATH=$PWD` (standing at the root of a Golang clone tree), your answer can't possibly explain the error in this case.

Comment: For me, putting it in $GOPATH was not enough. It needed to be in a directory under $GOPATH/src/

Comment: This didn't solve problem for me.
But this one did.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134975/go-install-no-install-location-for-directory-outside-gopath#answer-27428046

Comment: Hope this helps. OSX is actually case-insensitive. Though `/my/gopath` and `/my/Gopath` mean the same thing for OSX, but go seems to treat them differently. So, before `go install`, make sure the `pwd` command in current directory has the same case as the one you have in `GOPATH`.

Comment: I had to make `$home/my-work-space/bin`, then `export GOBIN=` the new bin directory.

Comment: I'm sure there is some very good reason to justify the existence of `GOPATH`, but from the outside looking in, this seems completely mindless. Why do I have to mutate global environment variables just to build a package locally 

Comment: @Alexander you can set the environment variable in just the one shell where you run the command if you want, you don't have to set it globally

Comment: I don't get it. I have a location where I checkout my code say `~/work`. Isn't it weird to also have to store dependent source files there? Why couldn't I just work here and go retrieve dependencies in `~/go`?

Answer (score 213):

For any OS X users and future me, you also need to set `GOBIN` to avoid this confusing message on install and `go get`

```
mkdir bin 
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: You should not need to [set `GOBIN`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallTroubleshooting). If setting it to [`$GOPATH/bin`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) makes a difference, then something else is wrong with your setup or you're doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: I also got the same error message but found that GOPATH was set but not exported in bash. export GOPATH solved the problem

Comment: @DaveC I too have the same problem on OS X. Setting the GOBIN fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks like something with the official OS X package is wrong indeed requiring you to set GOBIN, still valid for 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

Comment: This is correct fix for Ubuntu 16.04 as well, with binary package from [http://golang.org/dl/](http://golang.org/dl/)

Comment: I had the same issue when using the golang docker image on Gitlab CI. exporting the `GOBIN` made the difference.

Comment: This worked perfectly on maOS Sierra 10.12.3

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue on OSX, Thank You!

Comment: I had to set it on MacOS High Sierra just now to make it work. `go version go1.7.5 darwin/amd64` installed via brew.

Comment: Still had to do this as of go1.12.4

Comment: Still have to set GOBIN in Catalina 10.15.

Comment: thanks , I was missing the GOBIN. after setting GOBIN, install worked for  as I am setting up my workspace in a different folder than GOROOT.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 I ran into this error when I didn't have GOBIN set, even though GOPATH was at the default location, and contained a 'bin' directory.

Answer (score 30):

You are using *go install* on a directory outside the GOPATH folder.
Set your GOBIN env variable, or move *src* folder inside GOPATH.

```
GOPATH/
     bin/
     src/
       go-statsd-client/
```

More info: [GO BUILD Source code](http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/build.go), line 296

Comment: I tried the suggestion above (export GOPATH=$HOME), then moved into my relevant directory (where I am writing my code) and typed go install ...same result go install: no install location for directory ....

Comment: Line 296 is just a return statement?

Comment: I forgot to set my GOBIN env

Comment: I went for this solution.

Answer (score 27):

You need to setup both `GOPATH` and `GOBIN`. Make sure you have done the following (please replace `~/go` with your preferred `GOPATH` and subsequently change `GOBIN`). This is tested on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.

```
export GOPATH=~/go 

mkdir ~/go/bin

export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

The selected answer did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I have both defined in 16.04 and this did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to have 3 directories inside your chosen GOPATH directory.

```
GOPATH
     /bin
     /src
       /someProgram
        program.go
       /someLibrary
        library.go
     /pkg
```

Then you'll run `go install` from inside either someProgram (which puts an executable in bin) or someLibrary (which puts a library in pkg).

Comment: This worked for me after searching for 2 hours on internet.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on Windows.

My problem was that my `%GOPATH%` environment variable was set to

`C:\Users\john\src\goworkspace`

instead of

`C:\Users\john\src\goworkspace\`

Adding the missing trailing slash at the end fixed it for me.

Comment: holy cow you just saved me from a potentially multi-hour headache. I'm on Ubuntu but had the same problem. Was extremely diligent about folder names, folder structure, prefacing with src/github.com/xyabz/ and everything but go install kept giving me errors.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's my .bash_profile, that works well for me on a mac with Atom, after installing go with Homebrew:

```
export GOROOT=`go env GOROOT`
export GOPATH=/Users/yy/Projects/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (OS X) it was because I have set `GOPATH` to `/home/username/go` (as per the book) instead of `/Users/username/go`

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Windows, and I got it by giving command `go help gopath` to cmd, and read the bold text in the instruction,

that is if code you wnat to install is at `..BaseDir...\SomeProject\src\basic\set`, the **GOPATH** should not be the same location as code, it should be just Base Project DIR: `..BaseDir...\SomeProject`.

> The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code. On
>   Unix, the value is a colon-separated string. On Windows, the value is
>   a semicolon-separated string. On Plan 9, the value is a list.
>
> If the environment variable is unset, GOPATH defaults to a
>   subdirectory named "go" in the user's home directory ($HOME/go on
>   Unix, %USERPROFILE%\go on Windows), unless that directory holds a Go
>   distribution. Run "go env GOPATH" to see the current GOPATH.
>
> See https://golang.org/wiki/SettingGOPATH to set a custom GOPATH.
>
> Each directory listed in GOPATH must have a prescribed structure:
>
> The src directory holds source code. The path below src determines the
>   import path or executable name.
>
> The pkg directory holds installed package objects. As in the Go tree,
>   each target operating system and architecture pair has its own
>   subdirectory of pkg (pkg/GOOS_GOARCH).
>
> **If DIR is a directory listed in the GOPATH, a package with source in
>   DIR/src/foo/bar can be imported as "foo/bar" and has its compiled form
>   installed to "DIR/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/foo/bar.a".**
>
> The bin directory holds compiled commands. Each command is named for
>   its source directory, but only the final element, not the entire path.
>   That is, the command with source in DIR/src/foo/quux is installed into
>   DIR/bin/quux, not DIR/bin/foo/quux. The "foo/" prefix is stripped so
>   that you can add DIR/bin to your PATH to get at the installed
>   commands. If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are
>   installed to the directory it names instead of DIR/bin. GOBIN must be
>   an absolute path.
>
> Here's an example directory layout:
>
> ```
> GOPATH=/home/user/go
>
> /home/user/go/
>     src/
>         foo/
>             bar/               (go code in package bar)
>                 x.go
>             quux/              (go code in package main)
>                 y.go
>     bin/
>         quux                   (installed command)
>     pkg/
>         linux_amd64/
>             foo/
>                 bar.a          (installed package object)
> ```
>
> ..........

if GOPATH has been set to Base Project DIR and still has this problem, in windows you can try to set **GOBIN** as  `Base Project DIR\bin` or `%GOPATH%\bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Careful when running

```
export GOPATH=$HOME
```

Go assume that your code exists in specific places related to `GOPATH`. So, instead, you can use docker to run any go command:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/go/src/github.com/<organization name>/<repository name> golang
```

And now you can use any golang command, for example:

```
go test github.com/<organization name>/<repository name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, my cmd window was already open when I set the GOPATH environment variable.
First I had to close the cmd and then reopen for it to become effective.

Answer (score -1):

On OSX Mojave 10.14, `go` is *typically* installed at `/usr/local/go`.

Hence, setup these ENVs and you should be good to go.

`export GOPATH=/usr/local/go && export GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin`

Also, add these to your `bash_profile` or `zsh_profile` if it works.

`echo "export GOPATH=/usr/local/go && export GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`