# Can't get 'go install' to work on OSX

Tags: go

I'm having a look at Go however i'm stuck at the very first hurdle. Whenever I run 'go install' I get the following error:

```
go install: no install location for directory /Users/jamie/Sites/gocode/src/jd/hello outside GOPATH
```

In all of the other posts I've seen about this it's usually because the user hasn't set a GOPATH or is trying to run go install outside of the GOPATH. I have set up my GOPATH and my code is in my GOPATH.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/Users/jamie/Sites/gocode
    /bin
    /src
        /jd
            /hello
                hello.go
```

I'm trying to run 'go install' from inside /Users/jamie/Sites/gocode/src/jd/hello. Here is my GOPATH:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/james/Sites/gocode
```

And finally here is hello.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello there")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: go env:

```
$ go env
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="8"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/james/Sites/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_386"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread -fno-common"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your GOPATH cannot be the same as the Go installation. That is, if you compile Go and then try to use it's source directory for your source it will complain.

Comment: I don't think my GOPATH is the same as the installation dir. Go is installed in /usr/local/go - I used to OSX .pkg installer.

Comment: `go env` will show you what your Go install think it's various paths are. It might be worth checking that and adding it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've done this now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149601/go-install-always-fails-no-install-directory-outside-gopath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GOPATH="/Users/**james**/Sites/gocode" wheras your code is in /Users/**jamie**/Sites/gocode/src/jd/hello

So set `GOPATH=/Users/jamie/Sites/gocode` and hopefully it will work fine.

Comment: Well spotted, completely missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Set the GOPATH in what file. Sorry but OSX has changed shells often.