# Unable to run go install: no install location for directory outside GOPATH

Tags: go, installation

When I try to run `go install` I get the following:

```
go install golang-book/chapter11/math: mkdir /Users/Swanros/Go/pkg/darwin_amd64: permission denied
```

Then I try `sudo go install` and get the following:

```
go install: no install location for directory /Users/Swanros/Go/src/golang-book/chapter11/math outside GOPATH
```

Here's my `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/Swanros/Go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

`echo $GOPATH` outputs:

```
/Users/Swanros/Go
```

What am I missing? I've been dealing with this all morning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go install always fails no install directory outside GOPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149601/go-install-always-fails-no-install-directory-outside-gopath)

Comment: @DanielWilliams that's a permission problem, not a dup of that question you linked.

Comment: Don't use sudo when installing go packages. It will always continue to trip you up.

Comment: @JimB I know I shouldn't use ``sudo``, but I had to try it due to the error description. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a permission problem, changing the ownership on `$GOPATH` should fix it.

```
sudo chown -R $USER $GOPATH
```

I'm guessing that you somehow installed something as root that changed the permission of `$GOPATH/pkg`.

Comment: sudo does not preserve environment variables, so when you do sudo go install, it will whinge about GOPATH not being set correctly.

Comment: *bows down to the mighty @DaveCheney*