# go install: no install location for directory outside GOPATH

Tags: macos, path, go

I installed the Go, then added path requirements to my `.bash_profile`:

- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`
- `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`

I then setup the correct folders:

[image: Folders]

I also created a projected called **tire**.
The contents for `main.go` are simply:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

I always get the following error when I try to run `go install`:

`go install: no install location for directory /Users/Daryl/go/src/tire outside GOPATH`

Here's what I get when I run `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/daryl/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only thing that sticks out to me is that the case doesn't match between `GOPATH` and the directory where Go thinks your source is (`daryl` vs `Daryl`).  With a case sensitive filesystem, these would be different paths, so it may not know they are equivalent.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I think you could have nailed it. I created a new test user with a capitalised account name and it worked. Although, it doesn't really make sense to me why it wouldn't anyway, I've specified the lowercase in the GOPATH, so why is it using otherwise?

Comment: I don't have an OSX system to test, but I'd guess it is one of the following: (1) the directory really is capitalised (run `ls /Users` to check), or (2) `getcwd` is returning a capitalised version of the directory name.

Comment: Yes, OSX (specifically HFS+) can be configured to be case-insensitive and case preserving.

Comment: try setting up GOBIN="/Users/daryl/go/bin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was as James Henstridge [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134975/go-install-no-install-location-for-directory-outside-gopath?noredirect=1#comment40964222_26134975), for some reason there was an issue with my user directory name case. Even though the directory *is* lowercase, I had to make it capitalized.

This worked:

`GOPATH=/Users/Daryl/go`

This didn't:

`GOPATH=$HOME/go`

However, since moving to a rMBP from my iMac, I had no problems whatsoever setting up Go, so, to this day, I'm not sure what was going on, but in that instance the capitalization fixed it.

Answer (score 73):

When you run `go install` Go looks for `$GOBIN` env variable path. Either you need to set your `$GOBIN` to `$GOPATH/bin`

```
$ export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

and/or add `$GOBIN` to your OS search path

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

To use the command without getting the error.

Comment: I think that where you say `export GOBIN=$GOPATH:bin` you should say `export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: This is it for me as well! I've only set $GOPATH not $GOBIN, as soong as $GOBIN is set, everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 10,

So I set a system variable named `GOBIN`
with **absolute** value `F:\go\bin`.

Then ran `go install main.go` and everything worked perfectly fine!