# go install : directory outside of GOPATH

Tags: macos, go

I've just installed Go and I can't get my `go install` working. I followed a tutorial on YouTube to write a HelloWorld.go app but I keep getting the error:

`go install: no install location for directory /Users/####/Documents/Dev/go/src/github.com/####/hello outside GOPATH`

Here is my `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/####/Documents/Dev/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

In the tutorial that I was following the persons GOPATH was also set to a folder and then I was meant to create the folders /src/github.com/.....etc and then run `go install` in the directory with my code. Here's the code, although I imagine that not much could be wrong with the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world!");
}
```

When I run the `pwd` command inside the directory with my code, this is the output:
`/Users/####/Documents/Dev/go/src/github.com/####/hello`

When I run the `echo $GOPATH` command inside the directory with my code, this is the output:
`/Users/####/Documents/Dev/go`

I am running Mac OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Can you clarify what directory your code in? $GOPATH/src/github.com/####/hello or /src/github.com/####/hello?

Also, for hello world you don't have to use github.com/username/hello pattern - unless you really want to host it on github. You can use $GOPATH/src/test/hello or something like that.

Because clearly you have some confusion with directories.

Comment: The code is in $GOPATH/src/github.com/####/hello, and I decided to set up the file structure with the github pattern because I'll host my code on github in the future. Just maybe not with the HelloWorld app.

Comment: Post the output of 'pwd' and 'echo $GOPATH' commands. You are running 'go install' in the directory that is outside of $GOPATH.

Comment: `pwd: /Users/####/Documents/Dev/go/src/github.com/####/hello`

`echo $GOPATH: /Users/####/Documents/Dev/go`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. GOBIN environment variable

I'd suggest you read documentation about the `go` command, specifically [the section on the GOPATH envvar](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable). Quoting:

> The bin/ directory holds compiled commands. Each command is named for its source directory, but only the final element, not the entire path. That is, the command with source in DIR/src/foo/quux is installed into DIR/bin/quux, not DIR/bin/foo/quux. The foo/ is stripped so that you can add DIR/bin to your PATH to get at the installed commands. If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to the directory it names instead of DIR/bin.

Go is likely trying to install your program here, and running into permissions errors. Might just be a poor error message. In any case, it's unclear to me why you have `$GOBIN` set. To add the `go` tool to your PATH, add the directory directly: `export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH`

2. Case-insensitive filesystem

If that doesn't work, check the case of your home directory, as was the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430341.