# How to import local packages in go?

Tags: go

I am new to go and working on an example code that I want to localize.

In the original `main.go` import statement it was:

```
 import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/foo/bar/myapp/common"
    "github.com/foo/bar/myapp/routers"
)
```

Now I have `common` and `routers` package in `/home/me/go/src/myapp`

So I converted the import statement to:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "./common"
    "./routers"
)
```

But when I run `go install myapp` I get these errors:

```
can't load package: /home/me/go/src/myapp/main.go:7:3: local import "./common" in non-local package
```

Also, when I use `common` and `routers` instead of `./common` and `./routers` in the import statement, I get:

```
myapp/main.go:7:3: cannot find package "common" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/common (from $GOROOT)
    /home/me/go/src/common (from $GOPATH)
myapp/main.go:8:2: cannot find package "routers" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/routers (from $GOROOT)
    /home/me/go/src/routers (from $GOPATH)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: All imports are "local" regardless of the import path. See ["How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @JimB putting aside the philosophical debates, what I am concerned is how to solve the problem mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a philosophical statement, I'm literally saying *all* imports happen in your local filesystem; there is never any difference whether they originate from a remote repo or not. Don't try to use relative paths (they work sometimes, but are discouraged), and go through the "How to Write Go Code" document, specifically the section on ["Code Organization"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing local packages within a go module (go 1.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026284/accessing-local-packages-within-a-go-module-go-1-11)

Comment: The "How to Write Go Code" will invite you to create modules in a shared, global folder ($HOME/hello/morestrings for instance) which seems highly unnatural when coming from other backgrounds. But relative paths are not good either. 
The "vendor" answer below is an interesting intermediate. In JavaScript, it is similar to using a path alias to a local "packages" folder, that mimicks "real" packages, but let you keep the code within your app. It's useful when you refactor code, but you are not yet sure you actually want the module to be totally independant from the app.

Comment: And of course the accepted answer also works well, just figuring out the right module name: import "mymodulename/mynestedpackagename"

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem. 
Basically Go starting path for import is `$HOME/go/src`

So I just needed to add `myapp` in front of the package names, that is, the import should be:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "myapp/common"
    "myapp/routers"
)
```

Comment: using project name like `myapp` is a bad idea, for example if you change the project name, all the import will be failed

Comment: What's the alternative? Go doesn't recommend that you use relative imports.

Comment: Of course all the imports will fail if you change the project name. The project name rarely changes.

Comment: Well, as of go1.11 you can use the new modules system. `go mod init <module_name>` and then just `import "<module_name>/<pkg_name>"`.

Comment: How we can import github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go in our .go file? My jwt-go folder is inside src/github.com/dgrijalva

Comment: This answer would deserve a bit more details as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877864/5513532
Here are my takes:
- you need a go.mod only at the root, "myapp/go.mod" for instance with "module myapp"
- the nested folders don't need a go.mod.
- package vs module can be confusing but basically the convention seems to be "module/nestedFolderName": module is what you find in "go.mod" (myapp)
- if it doesn't work, you may have another issue (eg you created your app accidentally in a preexisting module folder, misconfigured text editor...)

Comment: The first sentence might be outdated, "Basically Go starting path for import is $HOME/go/src" => with go modules, the main app won't necessarily live in "$HOME/go/src", which can be confusing.
So the comment above from @shriek as well as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877864/5513532 are more appropriate in 2022
The main app should be created using "go mod init", and then the import path is just "module/folder".

Answer (score 88):

You should have created your package with `go mod init` e.g. `go mod init github.com/my-org/my-package`

Now in `my-package` you have a sub module called `utils` for example.

```
main.go
utils
 |- randstr.go
```

And your `randstr.go` looks like this:

```
package utils

func RandStr(n int) string {
    // TODO: Generate random string....
    return "I am a random string"
}
```

And then anywhere in your project you would use exported (capitalized) functions from the `utils` package like this, for example in `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    // "github.com/my-org/my-package" is the
    // module name at the top of your `go.mod`
    "github.com/my-org/my-package/utils"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Random string: %s\n", utils.RandStr(20))
}
```

Comment: I found your answer to be simple to understand. In general, is it correct to say, that by simply copying the required files in the module directories and following your simple instructions, one can eliminate the use of any Version Control System and still be able to use go modules? I simply do not like the notion of tying version control system to a language's development system and add the related complexities if I can maintain all code, including vendor-ed one locally, by simply copying them. As I get more confident with go, I may integrate use of modules-with-versioning support.

Comment: Worked well for me. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you, been almost a day trying to understand import/export in go after moving from nodejs. The easiest answer I found to date.

Comment: The capitalisation had me pulling my hair out for a moment.

Answer (score 68):

If you are using Go 1.5 above, you can try to use **vendoring** feature. 
It allows you to put your local package under **vendor** folder and import it with shorter path.
In your case, you can put your **common** and **routers** folder inside **vendor** folder
so it would be like

```
myapp/
--vendor/
----common/
----routers/
------middleware/
--main.go
```

and import it like this

```
import (
    "common"
    "routers"
    "routers/middleware"
)
```

This will work because Go will try to lookup your package starting at your project’s vendor directory (if it has at least one .go file) instead of $GOPATH/src.

FYI: You can do more with vendor, because this feature allows you to put "all your dependency’s code" for a package inside your own project's directory so it will be able to always get the same dependencies versions for all builds. It's like npm or pip in python, but you need to manually copy your dependencies to you project, or if you want to make it easy, try to look govendor by Daniel Theophanes

For more learning about this feature, try to look up here

[Understanding and Using Vendor Folder by Daniel Theophanes](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)

[Understanding Go Dependency Management by Lucas Fernandes da Costa](http://lucasfcosta.com/2017/02/07/Understanding-Go-Dependency-Management.html)

I hope you or someone else find it helpfully

Comment: you mean go lang version 1.15?

Comment: @arimaulana works perfectly well for me - GO 1.8 !

Comment: VS Code is not happy, do you know how to tell it to look for packages in the vendor folder? This questions is not answered at the time of writing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602601/how-to-allow-vendor-folder-support-in-visual-studio-code
Edit: fixed it by moving my project into its own folder, now it seems to work out of the box. I need a "go.mod" only at top level, not in vendor modules.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. Vendoring seems to be the best approach for importing local packages.

Comment: Note that your project **must** contain a `go.mod` file that specifies a recent-enough go version for this to work. From [`go-build`'s man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/golang-go/go-build.1.en.html#mod): "By default, if a vendor directory is present and the go version in go.mod  is 1.14 or higher, the go command acts as if -mod=vendor were set."

Answer (score 25):

Import paths are relative to your `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` environment variables. For example, with the following `$GOPATH`:

```
GOPATH=/home/me/go
```

Packages located in `/home/me/go/src/lib/common` and `/home/me/go/src/lib/routers` are imported respectively as:

```
import (
    "lib/common"
    "lib/routers"
)
```

Comment: Yes, the first example was my mistake.

Comment: What you mean by relative path not supported by the tooling?

Comment: You can't `go install` packages that uses relative imports.

Comment: I think its misunderstanding here. I mean relative to GOPATH. Not just relative like "../../mypackage"

Comment: That was in reference to the part you fixed about importing relative to the current directory. Yes, all user imports are relative to `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: But I already have `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` in my `.bashrc`. How putting the files in `/lib` make a difference?

Comment: to import package you need to add relative to `$GOPATH/src` path to your project.  `lib/` is just example

Comment: If you are using Go1.11 above, you can follow this [post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/import-and-use-local-packages-in-your-go-application-885c35e5624) for keeping the relative path

Answer (score 16):

Follow instructions here https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/call-module-code

Mainly you need the replace call in your go.mod file.

```
module example.com/hello

go 1.16

replace example.com/greetings => ../greetings
```

Answer (score 13):

an example:

1. in `./greetings`, do `go mod init example.com/greetings`
2. from another module, do `go mod edit -replace=example.com/greetings=../greetings`
3. `go get example.com/greetings`

from the [go tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/call-module-code)

Comment: I'm running Go 1.18 and this does not work. `go mod tidy` does not update the dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

Local package is a annoying problem in go.

For some projects in our company we decide not use sub packages at all.

- `$ glide install`
- `$ go get`
- `$ go install`

All work.

For some projects we use sub packages, and import local packages with full path:

`import "xxxx.gitlab.xx/xxgroup/xxproject/xxsubpackage`

But if we fork this project, then the subpackages still refer the original one.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach, available since `go1.18`, is to use a `go.work` file.

First, the local `common` package has to be a module, so provide a `go.mod` file inside the `common` folder:

```
module common

go 1.18
```

You can now create a `go.work` file in the root of your directory manually or call `go work init`, then `go work use .` and finally `go work use ./common`. It will look like this:

```
go 1.18

use (
    .
    ./common
)
```

Finally you can import the package in your code by name

```
package main

import "common"
```

Just remember to not commit your `go.work` files :)

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to commit the `go.work` file if the paths in it are relative to the project anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that. Afaik we use a local package while working on it before publishing into it's own repo. Once it's published, there's no need for importing a local package since you can import it normally. If you have a local copy of the package you just use go.work as it is designed. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @karlom in 2023, this should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

As in the question, the folder structure is:

```
/home/me/go/src/myapp
                └─ common
                └─ routers
```

So go to **myapp** dir

```
cd /home/me/go/src/myapp
```

Do

```
go mod init myapp
```

This will create a *go.mod* file which lets Go know the name of the module **myapp** so that when it’s looking at import paths in any package, it knows not to look elsewhere for **myapp**

Then you can do the following in the code:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "myapp/common"
    "myapp/routers"
)
```

Now package common and routers gets imported.

Answer (score 4):

The key is how you name your module in the following command

```
go mod init <TheNameGiven>
```

Then refer the modules in the inner folder with,

```
TheNameGiven/folder
```

I have found the best solution here... [Read More](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-import-local-files-packages-in-golang)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the package name with the *go mod init* command.

So, I have go 1.17, and I have the same import problem. My project directory is **$GOPATH/src/myswagger/app-swagger-test**. I ran this command into **app-swagger-test** dir:

```
go mod init app-swagger-test
go mod tidy
```

In my new go.mod file the package name is app-swagger-test. For example, this import was wrong:

```
import (
    ...
    "myswagger/app-swagger-test/internal/generated/restapi"
    "myswagger/app-swagger-test/internal/generated/restapi/operations"
)
```

So I removed go.mod and go.sum. And I ran next commands into **app-swagger-test** dir:

```
go mod init myswagger/app-swagger-test
go mod tidy
```

After that all imports in the project were imported successfully. In the new go.mod file the first line is:

```
module myswagger/app-swagger-test
```

Maybe this information is common, but I did not find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GOMODULE111=on, then

1. The local module being imported (and packages within) can be anywhere on your local machine. No need to know about GOPATH or GOROOT or GOPRIVATE or GONOPROXY.
2. The local module need not be published on any vcs.
3. The only requirement is for local module's module path in its go.mod to be defined as string1.string2/string3. All 3 can be arbitrary strings. No need to make string1.string2 as github.com or any such valid url. string3 need not even match the local directory at which the module is located.

Suppose, your local module is located at "/Users/me/dir_mod"

Then the go.mod within it should declare the module path as:
"module abc.def/xyz"

Suppose the module has a package at a "/Users/me/dir_mod/dir_package".

This package folder has file somefile.go declaring its package as "package random"

Note: The module path as well as the package name are not required to be the same as their respective actual directory names.

Let's say, you want to now import "random" package in another module.

The go.mod of calling project requires 2 lines (without the quotes):

1. "replace abc.def/xyz v0.0.0 => /Users/me/dir_mod"
2. "require abc.def/xyz v0.0.0"

The version number can be any random vX.Y.Z format string where X, Y, and Z have characters only between 0-9 (e.g. v1.2.3, v0.100.2, v00.1.345).

Now any file in a package inside the calling module can do:

"import another_random abc.def/xyz/dir_package" => using aliasing of packages to rename "package random" contained in ""/Users/me/dir_mod/dir_package"" as "another_random"

---

The above is just to illustrate that except for module path naming convention of abc.def/xyz and including a pseudo-version number, everything else is flexible. You wouldn't be having mixed names of packages and directories in real projects, but is helpful to know what is absolutely essential vs not.