# How to allow "vendor" folder support in visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I recently moved to the Visual Studio Code free editor for Go project. I performed all the initial setup starting from installing Go plugin etc.

However, the packages which are stored in my project's `vendor` folder are not recognized. When I was using Goland editor before, there was no issue.

It gives the following error.

```
20:5: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.17/libexec/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/abc/workspace/proj/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
    /Users/abc/workspace/projgopath/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1
```

I have my project file structure as follows:

```
proj
  +---src
       +---vendor
```

I have the settings.json file as below:

```
{
    "go.gopath": "/Users/abc/workspace/proj/:/Users/abc/workspace/projgopath/",
    "go.lintOnSave": "off",
    "go.vetOnSave": "off",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "go.toolsGopath": "/Users/abc/workspace/toolsgopath",
    "go.goroot": "",
    "eslint.runtime": ""
}
```

As far as I know, we do not have to specify the 'vendor' folder under GOPATH like the project path as mentioned above. The 'src' is implicitly added by the Go compiler when it tries to resolve/locate other application code, but not vendor.

As a workaround, I can copy all go packages installed in `'vendor'` to `"/Users/abc/workspace/projgopath/src"` but I am trying to avoid it, as it is a manual task.

Can you help how do I configure and make this work in Visual Source Code editor? Do I have to install any plugin to make this work? I am using the version: 1.44.0 of Visual Source Code editor.

Comment: Aren't you using Go modules? If no, then are you in GOPATH. I saw VSCode plugins not working outside of GOPATH.

Comment: set `GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor` and open the visual code after it

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a go.mod file

`go mod init github.com/username/project`

or move the project inside of your `GOPATH`

Comment: are you suggesting to run 'go mode init' under each package inside 'vendor' folder?