# How to import local packages in GOLANG?

Tags: go

I am new to GO (and procedural programming) and I was working on an example code

My main.go import statement is

```
package main

 import (
     "fmt"
     "packagetest/mymath"
 )

 func main() {
     fmt.Println(mymath.Add(2, 3))
 }
```

My mymath.go package is

```
package mymath

func Add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func sub(a, b int) int {
    return a - b
}
```

My GOPATH is C:\Users\tonyf\Desktop\go-workspace-2.0

This is where my main.go is `C:\Users\tonyf\Desktop\go-workspace-2.0\src\packagetest`

This is where my mymath.go is `C:\Users\tonyf\Desktop\go-workspace-2.0\src\packagetest\mymath`

When I run main.go i get a error like this
`main.go:5:2: package packagetest/mymath is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\packagetest\mymath)`

And problem

```
could not import packagetest/mymath (cannot find package "packagetest/mymath" in any of 
    C:\Program Files\Go\src\packagetest\mymath (from $GOROOT)
    C\src\packagetest\mymath (from $GOPATH)
    \Users\tonyf\Desktop\go-workspace-2.0\src\packagetest\mymath (from $GOPATH))
```

Please Help

Comment: [How to Write go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) is a step by step guide to creating and using multiple packages in a module.

Comment: The tutorial [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) describes how [to use packages in your own module](https://golang.org/doc/code#ImportingLocal).

Comment: See also the practically-identical question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480623/how-to-import-local-packages-in-go

Answer (score -1):

You just need to run this command first:

```
go mod init <appname>
```

in the same application path.