# Can someone please dumb down go mod init for me?

Tags: go

I am trying to use the module capabilities of go to understand how they work. I have read the documentation and even replicated the exact process and for some reason the import of local modules. The file tree is like this

```
    src
     |
      main -> main.go
     |
     pkg -> pkg.go
```

The src folder has two folders main and pkg.

My question is where should I call `go mod init` and how should I name it. This has been confusing me for a while now.

Comment: The official docs have a [step by step tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module), and the [linked reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-init) explains `go mod init` in detail. You run `go mod init` where you want to initialize your module, and you name it what you want to name your module. What specific questions do you have?

Comment: A "module" is a set of packages versioned together. You put your go.mod somewhere and put all packages with the same lifecycle in a folder below. Anything else doesn't matter. Just read the official tuttorial.

Comment: The introductory tutorial [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) covers your scenario.  The tutorial shows how [write a program in a module](https://golang.org/doc/code#Command) that [imports a package from the same module](https://golang.org/doc/code#ImportingLocal).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. I spent the whole day going through the documentation and going through this book called "head first go", but couldn't import the modules I made.

Comment: Although it doesn't explain the name chosen for use with `go mod init`, this is probably the best place to start: [Tutorial: Get started with Go](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started). A key point is that "Enable dependency tracking for your code" is optional for the most trivial cases like `go run hello.go`, but is essentially required for any non-trivial applications or workflows (for example using non-standard imports).

Comment: Another point that is rarely mentioned is that it basically doesn't matter what you use as the module name if you're building a main module that you don't plan to import elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use Windows paths, as that's what I use. First, make a new folder somewhere, for example `C:\north`. They go to that directory, and enter this:

```
go mod init north
```

Then make `C:\north\north.go`:

```
package north

const Direction = "north"
```

Then make `C:\north\north\north.go`:

```
package main
import "north"

func main() {
   println(north.Direction)
}
```

Comment: A module name that is not a URI is fine for testing and local development, but it's also one more thing to trip up new users which can easily be avoided.

Comment: This does solve my problem but I will not be able to explain how this work, I will study from the notes that you people linked. Thanks for your time.